# Problemas con el ReCaptcha V3

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha

Estoy intentando hacer una verificación por ReCaptcha cuando un usuario se registra, pero me encuentro con un error que no me deja seguir, se trata del error `{"success":false,"message":"Error en el reCAPTCHA. Por favor, completa la verificaci\u00f3n."}`

He estado utilizando ReCaptcha V3, pero me aparece ese error. Mi código consta de varias partes, de un HTML, un JS y un PHP.

(He incluido la biblioteca de Javascript:

```
<!-- Recapchta -->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

)

Primero, mi HTML es un formulario y en el boton submit del formulario tengo este codigo:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="g-recaptcha-response"
class="g-recaptcha w-full text-white bg-orange-600 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800"
data-sitekey="my-key" data-callback='onSubmit'data-action='submit'>Regístrate</button>
```

Luego, manejo el envío del formulario con AJAX de esta manera:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
            document.getElementById('registroForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var formData = new FormData(this);

                fetch('register.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        if (data.success) {
                            // Mostrar mensaje de éxito
                            alert(data.message);
                            // Redirigir al usuario a una página específica
                            window.location.href = './tests.html';
                        } else {
                            // Mostrar mensaje de error
                            alert(data.message);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
            });
        }
```

Y por último, tengo mi PHP que realiza la verificación del lado del servidor:

```
<?php
// Verificar el reCAPTCHA
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $recaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
        'secret' => '6LffLykmAAAAAOf2KJq3XTaRG280E9CWuI5DS-fi',
        'response' => $recaptchaResponse
    ]));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $recaptchaResult = json_decode($response);

    if ($recaptchaResult->success) {

        // Conexión a la base de datos
        $servername = "***";
        $username = "***";
        $db_password = "***";
        $dbname = "****";
        $port = 3306;

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname, $port);

        // Comprobar la conexión
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            error_log("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
            die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Verificar si se recibieron los datos del formulario
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
            // Obtener los valores del formulario
            $nombre = sanitizeInput($_POST["nombre"]);
            $apellido = sanitizeInput($_POST["apellido"]);
            $email = sanitizeEmail($_POST["email"]);
            $password = sanitizeInput($_POST["password"]);

            // Consulta de inserción
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (nombre, apellido, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

            // Verificar si la preparación de la consulta tuvo éxito
            if ($stmt === false) {
                error_log("Error en la consulta: " . $conn->error);
                die("Error en la consulta: " . $conn->error);
            }

            // Encriptar la contraseña (por ejemplo, usando Argon2)
            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);

            // Asignar los valores a los parámetros de la consulta
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nombre, $apellido, $email, $hashedPassword);

            // Ejecutar la consulta
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                // Registro insertado correctamente
                $response = array(
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => 'Registro insertado correctamente.'
                );

                // Establecer las cookies
                setcookie('remember', '1', time() + (10 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', '');
                setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, "/", "");
                header('Location: tests.html');
            } else {
                // Error al insertar el registro
                $response = array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Error al insertar el registro: ' . $stmt->error
                );
            }

            // Cerrar la consulta
            $stmt->close();
        }

        // Cerrar la conexión
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Error en el reCAPTCHA. Por favor, completa la verificación.'
        );
    }
} else {
    $response = array(
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'No se proporcionó el reCAPTCHA. Por favor, completa la verificación.'
    );
}

echo json_encode($response);

function sanitizeInput($input) {
    // Aplica la sanitización adecuada según tus necesidades
    $sanitizedInput = trim($input);
    $sanitizedInput = stripslashes($sanitizedInput);
    $sanitizedInput = htmlspecialchars($sanitizedInput);
    return $sanitizedInput;
}

function sanitizeEmail($email) {
    // Sanitiza el correo electrónico utilizando el filtro de correo electrónico de PHP
    $sanitizedEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    return $sanitizedEmail;
}
?>
```

**EDITADO**
El error específico es: {"success":false,"message":"Respuesta de entrada no válida."}

Comment: Puedes pintar el error que te aparece en el llamado a la API de Google? Veo que muestras el error: `Error en el reCAPTCHA. Por favor, completa la verificación.`, el error de la API debería coincidir con alguno de los mencionados en la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#error_code_reference).

Comment: Hola! El error específico es:
{"success":false,"message":"Respuesta de entrada no válida."}

Comment: Ahora podrías hacerle un `print` a la variable `$recaptchaResult`?

Comment: Esto es lo que devuelve: stdClass Object ( [success] => [error-codes] => Array ( [0] => invalid-input-response ) ) {"success":false,"message":"Respuesta de entrada no v\u00e1lida."}

Comment: Comprobando que el error code es `invalid-input-response` podrían ser varios motivos, podrías probar estas cosas: 1.- Comprobar que tu host/sitio esté dado de alta correctamente en el panel de administración de reCaptcha. 2.- Comprobar que no estés mezclando el `site key` y el `secret key`.

Comment: Aunado a lo anterior al ser tu código PHP podrías intentar agregar esta parte: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($variaveis))); `

Comment: He intentado de todo, pero sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: Creo que `document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();` iría al final de tu función `onSubmit(token)`

Comment: No, sigue ocurriendo el mismo error @Cris223511.dev

Comment: Ya validaste que no estés utilizando algún servidor proxy en la configuración de red de Windows? Si de casualidad tienes un servidor proxy activo, desactívalo e intenta de nuevo con el reCAPTCHA.

Comment: También puedes validar el funcionamiento de **reCAPTCHA** desde esta demo de google, así puedes descartar que se trate de algún tema con la configuración de tu equipo o con la red. [Google ReCAPTCHA demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo)

Comment: Hola @RobertoRivera, no estoy utilizando un servidor proxy y la Demo me validó correctamente. Muchas gracias por el interés.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te diré como lo tengo yo funcionando y trataré de adecuarlo a lo tuyo

**1.- Cargo la librería**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"async defer> </script>
```

Cuando carga la Liberia llama a la función `onloadCallback`

```
var onloadCallback = function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
            grecaptcha.render('captc', {
                      'sitekey' : '6Leot4YUAAAAACTXXXX_PTYASDADVUxIiP-7',
                      'callback' : verifyCallback,
                    });
            resolve();
       });

  };
```

Esto hace que se llame a la función `verifyCallback` cuando valida el captcha

```
var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").setAttribute('disabled', false);
            resolve();
       });
    };
```

La función anterior es para habilitar el botón submit

**2.- El Form**

```
<form id="registroForm">
  <!-- Aquí todos los inputs  -->
  <div  id="captc" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
  <button id="btnSubmit" type="button"> Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Si te fijas el botón y el `g-recaptcha` los tengo separados

**3.- Javascript**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  
  const boton=document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
  
  //deshabilito el botón enviar
  boton.setAttribute('disabled', true);

  boton.addEventListener("click",Enviar);
});

function Enviar(){

    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("registroForm"));

    fetch('register.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            // Mostrar mensaje de éxito
            alert(data.message);
            // Redirigir al usuario a una página específica
            window.location.href = './tests.html';
        } else {
            // Mostrar mensaje de error
            alert(data.message);
        }
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

**4.- El PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
{
   $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
   $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Lfeot4Y3455435fjw8kp_P41ffHcURofsdfsdfEdt&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true); 

  if($response['success'])
  {
     //etc

  }
}
```